# What are the extremes of the function $ f\left(x,y\right)=xy\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}} $?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, extreme-value-analysis

$ f\left(x,y\right)=xy\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}} $
; where a,b are constants.

I have tried to differentiate the equation, but I get stuck in a very hard system after this.

The answer of the problem is:

$ f_{max}=\frac{ab}{3\sqrt{3}};f_{min}=-\frac{ab}{3\sqrt{3}} $

Comment: Hint: start with $x=ar,y=bs$ then it should be a little easier to see the symmetry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{f(x,y)}{ab}=\pm\sqrt{g(x^2/a^2,y^2/b^2)}$ where
$$g(u,v)=uv(1-u-v)\quad(u,v\ge0,u+v\le1).$$
$g_\min=0$ is attained all along the boundary of the triangle, so that $g_\max$ must be attained at some point of the interior ($u,v>0,u+v<1$).

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}=v(1-2u-v),$$
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}=u(1-u-2v),$$
and solving
$$1-2u-v=1-u-2v=0$$
you find that
$$g_\max=g(1/3,1/3)=1/27$$
hence
$$f_\max=\frac{ab}{\sqrt{27}}$$
(and $f_\min=-f_\max$).

Comment: Ok ... I got it until the part of $ \frac{f\left(x,y\right)}{ab}=\pm \sqrt{g\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2},\frac{y^2}{b^2}\right)} $ 

But how you manage to $ g_{max}=\frac{1}{27} $ ?

I'm having trouble in this part too, like, it's way simple to differentiate now, but the system that I get after still horrible ..

Comment: made it. 
thx so much, you dont know how much you helped me.

Answer (score 5):

I'll prove that $(f(x,y) - \frac{ab}{3\sqrt{3}})(f(x,y) + \frac{ab}{3\sqrt{3}}) \leq 0$ which is equivalent.

$(f(x,y) - \frac{ab}{3\sqrt{3}})(f(x,y) + \frac{ab}{3\sqrt{3}}) \leq 0 \iff$

$f(x,y)^2 - \frac{(ab)^2}{27}\leq 0 \iff$

$x^2y^2(1 -\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2}) \leq \frac{(ab)^2}{27} \iff$

$x^2y^2 \leq \frac{x^4y^2}{a^2} + \frac{x^2y^4}{b^2} + \frac{(ab)^2}{27}$ which is true by $AM-GM $.

Equality is achieved at $x = \pm\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $y = \pm\frac{b}{\sqrt{3}}$.

EDIT:

$AM-GM$ for 3 terms:

$3\sqrt[3]{pqr} \leq p+q+r$.

Take $p = \frac{x^4y^2}{a^2}, q=\frac{x^2y^4}{b^2}, r=\frac{(ab)^2}{27}$.

Comment: Your solution is complete, but it is not shown where constant $\frac{ab}{3\sqrt{3}}$ comes from

Comment: Could you please write more about AM-GM inequality usage?

Comment: Yea I added details.